# Spark zipPartitions on the same RDD

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I'm quite a newbie with Spark and I have some problem in doing something like a `cartesian` but only within the same partition. Maybe an example can swoh clearly what I want to do: let's suppose we have a RDD made with `sc.parallelize(1,2,3,4,5,6)` and this RDD is partitioned in three partitions which contains respectively: `(1,2)` ; `(3,4)` ; `(5,6)`. Than I would like to obtain the following result: `((1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2))` ; `((3,3),(3,4),(4,3),(4,4))` ; `((5,5),(5,6),(6,5),(6,6))`.

What I have tried so far is doing:

```
 partitionedData.zipPartitions(partitionedData)((aiter, biter) => {
  var res = new ListBuffer[(Double,Double)]()
  while(aiter.hasNext){
    val a = aiter.next()
    while(biter.hasNext){
      val b = biter.next()
      res+=(a,b)
    }
  }
  res.iterator
})
```

but it doesn't work as `aiter` and `biter` are the same iterator...so I get only the first line of the result.

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `RDD.mapPartitions`:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 6, 3)
val res = rdd.mapPartitions { iter =>
  val seq = iter.toSeq
  val res = for (a <- seq; b <- seq) yield (a, b)
  res.iterator
}
res.collect
```

Prints:

```
res0: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2), (3,3), (3,4), (4,3), (4,4), (5,5), (5,6), (6,5), (6,6))
```

Comment: Thanks for you response, I am quite a newbie to Scala. What is a seq? What I mean is how does it behave in terms of memory usage? Thanks.

Comment: `Seq` is a "trait" (an interface) so you can never be sure :). It looks like `Iterator.toSeq` creates a `Stream`, which is like a lazy linked list. Scala loves linked lists. You could try `toArray` instead of `toSeq` if you are concerned about memory usage.